# continuity of functions on intervals

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity

Suppose that $f : (a,b) \to \mathbb R$ is continuous. Then, there is a continuous $g : [a,b] \to \mathbb R$ such that $g(x) = f(x)$ for all $x \in (a,b)$. That is, a function defined and continuous on an open interval $(a,b)$ can be extended to a continuous function on all of $[a,b]$.

True or False? If true, prove. If false, give a counterexample.

I think its false. As a counterexample:

Let $f(x) = ({x^2}-x-2)/(x-2)$, where $x>2$. Then, $f:(2,\infty) \to \mathbb R$ is continuous.
Let $g : [2,\infty] \to \mathbb R$ such that $g(x) = f(x)$ for all $x \in (2,\infty)$.
Now, $g(x)$ is not defined on $x = 2$ and is therefore discontinuous.
Thus, a function defined and continuous on an open interval (a,b) cannot always be extended to a continuous function on all of $[a,b]$.

Is my answer correct?

Comment: Function $f:(2,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ as you defined can be extended by $g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, $x\mapsto x+1$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

What about $f:(0,1)\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x)=1/x$?

Comment: This function cannot be extended to a continuous function on all of [a,b]?

Comment: No, I see that function $\underline{can}$ be extended to a continuous function $g$ in many ways. So I sugest another function $f$ as you can see.

Comment: But the statement is false according to you right?

Comment: Yes, the statement is false.

Comment: Ok, so $f : (0,1) \to \mathbb R$ defined by $f(x) = 1/x$ cannot be extended?

Comment: Yes, cause $1/x\to\infty$ as $x\to 0^{+}$.

Answer (score 1):

Of course false!!!!!
Consider for example the function tan(x) in $(-\pi/2, \pi/2)$ which tends to $-\infty$ at $(-\pi/2)^+$ and tends to $+\infty$ at $(\pi/2)^-$. None continuous function $g$ defined on $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$ can extend $f=\tan$. (otherwise $g(-\pi/2)=+ \infty $ for example which impossible)